# Windows 7 Installation On UEFI and GPT HDD without converting to MBR

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, boot, partitioning, bios

I Have **ideapad 330 15IKB** Laptop with **GPT Hard Drive** and i'm trying to install **Windows 7**.

I tried to install it with **Legacy Boot** from **BIOS configuration**, but it failed to read the **Drives/Partitions** while installing. with error :

[image]

with some searching i figured that i need to use **UEFI** boot from **BIOS**.

so i used **Rufus** and created a **Bootable USB** with **Target System: UEFI (non CSM)** and **Partition Scheme: GPT** and **File System: NTFS** (the only choise)

[image]

After that when i boot from **UEFI** on the **USB Drive** i get this error :

[image]

By knowing that i have **Secure Boot: disabled** in **BIOS**.

i also tested lots of **Windows 7 ISO** original copies and i get the same error.

i tried to copy **\boot** folder from **\efi\microsoft** to **\efi** folder

and extracted **bootmgfw.efi** to **\efi\boot** and renamed it to **bootx64.efi**. and also getting the same error.

Tried a **CD** copy of **Windows 7** with **Legacy Support: Enabled**.

and i see the **Drives/Partitions** while installing, but the **Drives** are **GPT** and the **CD copy** is **MBR** so i will need to convert my HDD to **MBR** and i can't do that since i will have to wipe all my data on that HDD.

What causes this problem?

Thanks.

Comment: Is it a 32-bit windows 7? 32 bit does not support GPT.

Comment: Also, you must disable legacy boot.

Comment: @BhavyaGupta it is x64 and i've already tried to disable legacy boot and use uefi boot. it does the error above in the black screen i mentioned.